# Screen goes blank after installation and boot menu Ubuntu 12.04 (Windows Installer)

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, wubi, ubuntu-netbook, live-usb

Well my problem is taht after installing ubuntu, i restart my computer, and select ubuntu from the boot screen, the screen goes a purple color for a fraction of second and then it changes to black with a white blinking underscore on the top left, i have an HP notebook so i tried using usb with no results, then i tried the windows one, installed and reinstalled like 3 times, help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but instead of black, my screen was purple.  I upgraded from 11.04 to 12.04 and the upgrade went smoothly (no errors/no-warnings).  After the upgrade and re-boot the X-server was un-responsive.  No mouse/no keyboard.  ctl-alt-Fx did not work the keyboard was totally dead, caps-lock did not toggle the LED, but I could ssh from another machine.  I suspected it could be my non standard ATI graphics driver.  After a lot of searching I found a new AT installer but I had to uninstall the old one first.

1. Downloaded the newest AMD installer from http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/ATI-Radeon-Linux-Display-Drivers-Download-6719.html
2. Uninstalled the old  fglrx driver by `sudo apt-get remove fglrx`
3. `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run`

After step 2 I could restart my PC and things were better.  The mouse moved and I could type.  So I tried to install the latest AMD ATI driver and after a reboot it worked.

Machine Info:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 16
model           : 5
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 635 Processor
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x10000b6
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp
 lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt
lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch os
vw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
bogomips        : 5800.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 16
model           : 5
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 635 Processor
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x10000b6
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp
 lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt
lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch os
vw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
bogomips        : 5800.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 16
model           : 5
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 635 Processor
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x10000b6
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp
 lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt
lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch os
vw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
bogomips        : 5800.86
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 16
model           : 5
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 635 Processor
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x10000b6
cpu MHz         : 2900.000
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp
 lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt
lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch os
vw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
bogomips        : 5800.83
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate
```